# Converting Json To XML Throwing Exception "The ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a name"

Tags: c#, json, xml

I have a large JSON string that im trying to convert to xml. I am using JSON.net to do this and i have the following line of code.

```
XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(jsonstring);
```

When i execute this line it throws an exception

> "The ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a
>   name."

From what i could find this error is due to a space in the name for an xml node.I have checked over the JSON and there are no field names that have a space in the name. Some of the data values have spaces. e.g "addressFullName": "Mike Spark", but this should be fine since it is going within the node.

```
json = json.Replace(" ", "");
```

The line of code above resolves the error, but it removes the space between any strings like address info that needs to have the space.

UPDATE: Turns out there was 1 node with a space and 1 that is numeric. The code is coming from a web service so i have no control over the formatting. I need to find a way to remove spaces in field names or set some rules to force validity when there is an error detected.

The Stack trace is

```
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.CheckName(String name)
   at System.Xml.XmlElement..ctor(XmlName name, Boolean empty, XmlDocument doc)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.CreateElement(String prefix, String localName, String namespaceURI)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.CreateElement(String name)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlDocumentWrapper.CreateElement(String elementName)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.CreateElement(String elementName, IXmlDocument document, String elementPrefix, XmlNamespaceManager manager)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.ReadElement(JsonReader reader, IXmlDocument document, IXmlNode currentNode, String propertyName, XmlNamespaceManager manager)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.DeserializeValue(JsonReader reader, IXmlDocument document, XmlNamespaceManager manager, String propertyName, IXmlNode currentNode)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.DeserializeNode(JsonReader reader, IXmlDocument document, XmlNamespaceManager manager, IXmlNode currentNode)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.ReadElement(JsonReader reader, IXmlDocument document, IXmlNode currentNode, String propertyName, XmlNamespaceManager manager)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.DeserializeValue(JsonReader reader, IXmlDocument document, XmlNamespaceManager manager, String propertyName, IXmlNode currentNode)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.DeserializeNode(JsonReader reader, IXmlDocument document, XmlNamespaceManager manager, IXmlNode currentNode)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.ReadElement(JsonReader reader, IXmlDocument document, IXmlNode currentNode, String propertyName, XmlNamespaceManager manager)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.DeserializeValue(JsonReader reader, IXmlDocument document, XmlNamespaceManager manager, String propertyName, IXmlNode currentNode)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.DeserializeNode(JsonReader reader, IXmlDocument document, XmlNamespaceManager manager, IXmlNode currentNode)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.ReadElement(JsonReader reader, IXmlDocument document, IXmlNode currentNode, String propertyName, XmlNamespaceManager manager)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.DeserializeValue(JsonReader reader, IXmlDocument document, XmlNamespaceManager manager, String propertyName, IXmlNode currentNode)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.DeserializeNode(JsonReader reader, IXmlDocument document, XmlNamespaceManager manager, IXmlNode currentNode)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.ReadElement(JsonReader reader, IXmlDocument document, IXmlNode currentNode, String propertyName, XmlNamespaceManager manager)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.DeserializeValue(JsonReader reader, IXmlDocument document, XmlNamespaceManager manager, String propertyName, IXmlNode currentNode)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.DeserializeNode(JsonReader reader, IXmlDocument document, XmlNamespaceManager manager, IXmlNode currentNode)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonConverter[] converters)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(String value, String deserializeRootElementName, Boolean writeArrayAttribute)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(String value, String deserializeRootElementName)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(String value)
```

Comment: The error message indicates that you must have missed that name that has a space in it.  I would try to use a text editor to remove all the spaces and then take a diff of the converted file against the original file and try again to find the bad node name.

Comment: You were right i found the bad node. The issue is this json is coming from a web service so i cant change the source. I have written a Replace rule to prevent this issue, but i then found another one where the JSON name was a number which also caused an error since XML cant have numeric nodes. Is there some sort of force validate method of making sure all the nodes are valid. It doesnt matter if it slightly alters the node name as long as the data stays the same

Comment: You may have to parse to JSON object, walk the object tree and correct all the name properties that are wrong and then re-serialize into a string and then parse the XML.  If I get some free time, I can write a more specific answer with a code sample, but hopefully that will get you or someone else started on an answer.

Comment: See here for code that will replace JSON property names that are invalid XML entity names with valid alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106619/census-geocoder-json-output-convert-to-xml-dataset-using-json-net-in-c-sharp/30110138#30110138