# NewtonSoft JSON DeserializeXmlNode exception

Tags: c#, json, xml, json.net

I have a simple json body

```
   "widget": {
    "debug": "on",
    "window": {
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
    },
    "image": { 
        "src": "Images/Sun.png",
        "name": "sun1",
        "horizontal@Offset": 250,
        "vOffset": 250,
        "alignment": "center"
    },
    "text": {
        "data": "Click Here",
        "size": 36,
        "style": "bold",
        "name": "text1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 100,
        "alignment": "center",
        "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
    }
}}
```

So during deserialization using

```
 xmldoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(jsonBody, "widget")
```

I am getting this exception

```
The '@' character, hexadecimal value 0x40, cannot be included in a name.
```

My question is there any naming convention for NewtonSoft JSON parser, as it is not able to convert '@' character? If not, how to get rid of this exception?

Comment: That "@" simply doesn't make up a valid XML name. Looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30110138/21567) could be a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says @ is not valid character in the xml element's name as per W3C https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-Name .You might have to change horizontal@Offset